# .mm .h .c Files from copied phonegap project not shown in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ant, zxing

I have a phonegap project and split the code in global files (that are similar for android and ios) and ios/android specific files. Then I have an ant script where I merge the files into one project again.

The problem is I have a plugin "xzing barcode scanner". The files lay within the projectname/Plugins folder of the IOS project. The files are also merged to the target directory, but in xcode they´re not shown. And when I run the app I get the error that the plugin isn`t known.

This part of the ant scirpt copies the file

```
    <copy todir="${targetdir}/${projectName}.xcodeproj">
        <fileset dir="${projectroot}/${projectName}.xcodeproj"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${targetdir}/${projectName}">
        <fileset dir="${projectroot}/${projectName}"/>
    </copy>
```

The contents of the Plugin Folder:

```
CDVBarcodeScanner.mm
zxing_all_in_one.h
zxing_all_in_one.c
README
```

All Files are copied to the target directory (targetdir/projectname/Plugins), but somehow not merged into the project in xcode.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your files do not seem to be referenced to your XCode project.

I think a simple way you may try would be to copy your files manually like this (I don't know why but this kind of issue was solved for me like this XD...):

- Use your `Finder` to go to your folder `Plugin` and move the "hidden" files (`CDVBarcodeScanner.mm`, `zxing_all_in_one.h`, `zxing_all_in_one.c`, and `README`) somewhere else, on your Desktop for instance.
- Open XCode and create an empty file for the folder `Plugin` (**--> Through XCode:** right click on the folder `Plugin`, `New File...`->`iOS`->`Other`->`Empty`) and save the file as `CDVBarcodeScanner.mm` (for example)
- Open the file `CDVBarcodeScanner.mm` (for example), that you put on your Desktop for example, with a simple text editor and copy the content to your new created file in XCode
- Do the same for the remaining files:

  - `zxing_all_in_one.h`
  - `zxing_all_in_one.c`
  - `README`

Hope this solution will work for you. Let me know of your results.

Comment: Hi Littm, thanks for your answer. It also worked for me when I copy it manually, the goal was to get the project ready to install including the files via the ant script.